# updating column with UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

After doing more reading and research today I am changing the way I store timestamps in my db so they are all unix timestamps.  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in the below query is doing nothing and not sure why.  There is no error, but the current value does not change when the query is executed.

Expected result is unix timestamp at the moment of the update (ex 1400899111).  dtCurrLogin is type INT, not null, default 0.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin SET lastIP = currIP, currIP = ?, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin , dtCurrLogin = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $account_id));
```

This really does not make any sense... I can directly enter the query into phpmyadmin and it works... minus the binding and prepared statement. So, there must be something going on with that aspect in my php causing the problem.

Comment: This begs the question "what was wrong with the old way of storing time stamps?"

Comment: Being able to convert between tz's, sorting, comparing, etc makes this solution sound much better.

Comment: So this is a one off event. Create a new table. Copy one to the other with the conversion. Do not need PHP for this. Just use SQL. i.e. `insert into....`

Comment: Nope.  This is not a one off event.

Comment: How - You have decided to abandon one format and use unix time stamps instead. So how this is not a one off event?

Comment: Does it matter? The query is part of the user login... it will happen every time a user logs in.

Comment: It matters. If a one off event (that I thinl you should do) is just write a SQL. Then change the query for the login. Otherwise you have a half way house. An overhead each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have dtCurrLogin = the current unix timestamp.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())
```

so:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin SET lastIP = currIP, currIP = ?, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin , dtCurrLogin = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())  WHERE account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $account_id));
```

Comment: Still nothing... plus everything I read says the now() is optional.

Comment: I have found theory, and practice and are not always the same.